# console.error: React Native version mismatch

Tags: javascript, react-native, version, expo, mismatch

im getting this error, React Native version mismatch.

It says my javascript is version 0.62.0-rc.5 and my Native is version 0.61.4

It tells me to make sure to rebuild the native code.

Im using exponential to build my project. I've tried to change react native version a couple of times with no success.

Here are my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
```

Here is the error:

[image]

What should i do next?

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: Sure, there are my dependencies